# Remove None value and append to the new list while filtering db.query in SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, typeerror

I have a filter that looks for the correct order_id, order_status from a table named Work and returns a list of order_id and document_location if the filter has the correct values and the query looks like this:

```
loc_list = db.query(Work.order_id, Work.document_location).filter(Work.order_id == order_id, Work.status == "Finished").order_by(desc(Work.last_update)).limit(1).one_or_none()
new_location.append(loc_list)
```

It looks for the right order_id and status in the Work table and if Work.status != "Finished" then it appends None value to the new_location list as there is no order_id or document_location is found and the filtered list looks like this:

```
[None, None, None, None, None, ('Order_id12fb', 'order_12.pdf'),('Order_id13fb', 'order_13.pdf'), ('Order_id14fb', 'order_14.pdf'), ('Order_id15fb', 'order_15.pdf'), ('Order_id16fb', 'order_16.pdf'), None, None]
```

When I run my next logic using new_location list where I loop through the new_location list and return every single order_id and document_location:

```
for result in new_location:
    order_items = (result.document_location, result.order_id)
return order_items
```

it returns an error saying:

```
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
```

I am looking for a way to remove the None values within the db.query filter and append only order_id or document_location by ignoring None. Is there a way in sqlalchemy to handle this?

Comment: "When I run my next logic using new_location list" I don't understand what's happening here.  Can you [edit] the question to provide a [mre]?

Comment: @snakecharmerb I updated the section with what I am returning, hope it makes sense now

Comment: Do you actually need the `None`s in the query result? Would `loc_list = db.query(Work.order_id, Work.document_location).filter(Work.order_id == order_id, Work.status == "Finished").order_by(desc(Work.last_update)).limit(1).all()` do ?

Comment: @snakecharmerb I do not need the None's in my query result. I still get the same TypeError if I do `order_by(desc(Work.last_update)).limit(1).all()`

Comment: There's something not quite right here; I don't see how the code in the question can produce this particular TypeError. Can you [edit] the question to include a [mre] and the _complete_ error traceback please?